# Multiple file comparison

Tags: python

I want to compare multiple files (15-20), which are gzipped, and restore from them lines, that are common. But this is not so simple. Lines that are exact in certain columns, and also I would like to have for them count information in how many files they were present. If 1, the line is unique to a file, etc. Would be also nice to hold those file names as well.

each file looks st like this:

```
##SAMPLE=<ID=NormalID,Description="Cancer-paired normal sample. Sample ID 'NORMAL'">
##SAMPLE=<ID=CancerID,Description="Cancer sample. Sample ID 'TUMOR'">
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  NormalID_NORMAL CancerID_TUMOR
chrX    136109567       .       C       CT      .       PASS    IC=8;IHP=8;NT=ref;QSI=35;QSI_NT=35;RC=7;RU=T;SGT=ref->het;SOMATIC;TQSI=1;TQSI_NT=1;phastCons;CSQ=T|ENSG00000165370|ENST00000298110|Transcript|5KB_downstream_variant|||||||||YES|GPR101|||||        DP:DP2:TAR:TIR:TOR:DP50:FDP50:SUBDP50   23:23:21,21:0,0:2,2:21.59:0.33:0.00   33:33:16,16:13,13:4,4:33.38:0.90:0.00
chrX    150462334       .       T       TA      .       PASS    IC=2;IHP=2;NT=ref;QSI=56;QSI_NT=56;RC=1;RU=A;SGT=ref->het;SOMATIC;TQSI=2;TQSI_NT=2;CSQ=A||||intergenic_variant||||||||||||||| DP:DP2:TAR:TIR:TOR:DP50:FDP50:SUBDP50 30:30:30,30:0,0:0,0:31.99:0.00:0.00     37:37:15,17:16,16:6,5:36.7:0.31:0.00
```

Files are tab delimited.
If line starts with #, ignore this line. We are interested only in those, that do not.
Taking 0 based python coordinates, we are interested in 0,1,2,3,4 fields. They have to match between files to be reported as common. However we still need tohold information about the rest of the coulmns/fields, so that they can be written tot he output file

Right now I have the following code:

```
import gzip
filenames = ['a','b','c']
files = [gzip.open(name) for name in filenames]

sets = [set(line.strip() for line in file if not line.startswith('#')) for file in files]
common = set.intersection(*sets)
for file in files: file.close()
print common
```

In my currenyt code I do not know how to implement correctly the if not line.startswith() (which place?), and how to specify the columns in line that should be matched. Not to mention, that I have no idea how to get the lines that are for example present in 6 files, or present in 10 out of total 15 files.
Any help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the lines in a dictionary with the fields that make them similar as key:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

def process(filename, line):
    if line[0] == '#':
        return

    fields = line.split('\t')
    key = tuple(fields[0:5]) # Fields that makes lines similar/same
    d[key].append((filename, line))

for filename in filenames:
    with gzip.open(filename) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            process(filename, line.strip())
```

Now, you have a dictionary with lists of filename-line tuples. You can now print all the lines which appear more than 10 times:

```
for l in d.values():
   if len(l) < 10: continue

   print 'Same key found %d times:' % len(l)

   for filename, line in l:
       print '%s: %s' % (filename, line)
```

Comment: I have a following problem: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in lines: d[key].append and process(filename[...]

Comment: Ah, yes. try `key = tuple(fields[0:5])`

Comment: This is great answer, and the concept was understood right from the start. I will toy around myself with the nice output (btw the current one is already really nice and allows for very easy filtering). Many thanks